# Trees: How to identify/mark root objects when persisting?

Tags: java, sql, tree, rdbms

How would you persist root nodes of custom tree structures in such a way that they could be retrieved with a simple `SELECT` ?

**Pseudo-code**

```
class Node {
    Long id;
    String label;
    Node parent;
    List<Node> children;
}
```

Edit: Tables could be as follows. Feel free to suggest improvement.

```
CREATE TABLE NODES(
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    LABEL VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE PARENTS_CHILDREN(
    PARENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CHILD_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Very vague question IMO. Pesist where? What kind of "select" are you talking about?

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma Please refer to tags.

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: This is a theoretical question. However I'm using the latest MySQL.

Comment: Removed root tag as it referred to Unix systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an adjacency list:

```
node   parent
1      NULL
2      1
3      1
4      2
5      NULL
6      5
```

The root nodes can be found with `WHERE parent IS NULL`.

Comment: Great. This confirms my thoughts :) . I saw that tree implementations have no special case for root nodes. I just needed to be reassured on how they could be encoded.

Answer (score 1):

If each child node may have at most one parent, there's no need to model the relationships in a separate table. Also, to make loading trees faster at the cost of making changing the root slower, store the root node's ID in every row. This allows you to load all nodes for a tree in one fast query and build the tree on the client.

```
CREATE TABLE NODES(
    ID          INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ROOT_ID     INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PARENT_ID   INTEGER,
    LABEL       VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Comment: "This allows you to load all nodes for a tree in one fast query and build the tree on the client." - Very cool suggestion. Hadn't thought of that.